# Why isn't this jquery effect working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working through this course on Codecademy and once I finished and ran the code.. it worked just fine, but what I like to do is take the code from codecademy and set copy/paste it into my own jquery folder for reference/practice.

The goal for this project was to get the krypton to bounce 3 times in 500ms, and the script.js works in codecademy but not when I set it up locally.. does anybody know why?

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/main" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div></div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```
body {
background-image: url('http://bit.ly/UpQgJ6');

}

div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #008800;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#003500), to(#008800));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #003500, #008800); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #003500, #008800);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, #003500, #008800);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, #003500, #008800);
}
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
        $(this).effect('bounce', {times:3}, 500);
    }); 
});
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: You need to include `jQuery` for it to work!

Comment: You didnt include jquery core library

Comment: Isn't that what the first script tag in the body does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that you did't include jquery core library. Jquery UI won't work because it depend on jquery core. Put this above jquery ui script code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or you can change the version itself. See here all the version include:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: Oh I see it now... I was under the impression that the the ui contained the core jquery library. Wow, thanks to everyone for the quick reply.